# How can I correct "zsh parse error near do"

Tags: zsh

I'm relatively new to zsh and scripts in general. I need to write an automated command script in zsh with the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh


for ((i = 0; i < 41; i++));

export K='SOME NUMBER'

do ./A-PROGRAM *SOME FLAGS* $i *MORE FLAGS* $K 1 ;

done;
```

I get the following error: ***program.zsh:8: parse error near `do'***

How can i correct this? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: From the viewpoint of language design, the requirement that - syntactically - `for` must be the prefix of a statement, and that the next statement **must** be a `do`, is not particularily elegant. I don't think that one would do such a construct nowadays, if someone wanted to create a completely new shell language.

Comment: Unlike a `while` loop, a `for` loop doesn't not allow an arbitrary list of commands between `for` and `do`. (Indeed, `do` is a reserved word so that you *can* signal the end of an arbitrary command list.) `do` is part of the `for` syntax mainly for symmetry. `zsh` does provide a number of alternate loop forms that don't require `do`; see `man zshmisc`, under the section "Alternate Forms for Complex Commands" for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `EXPORT` doing there between the `for ()` and the `do`? And do you really need to `EXPORT` the variable `$K`. You seem to pass it as parameter to `A-PROGRAM` anyways?

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

K='SOME NUMBER'
for ((i = 0; i < 41; i++)); do
  ./A-PROGRAM *SOME FLAGS* $i *MORE FLAGS* $K 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved the issue. Yes, $K is a parameter for the program, I won't use export if not necessary from now on. Thanks again!